# Parsing forloop.counter in form's label in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am unsuccessfully trying to make the label of some forms I generate through a loop depend on `forloop.counter`. Here what I have so far:

```
{% for field in form %}

{% formfield field with label="blablabla {{ forloop.counter }}" %}

{% endfor %}
```

This returns the correct form but {{ forloop.counter }} appears as is in the label, instead of it being replaced by its value.

What am I doing wrong? I see this kind of construction everywhere in Django code, e.g. on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial04/

```
<h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/vote/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

What sets forms' labels apart from say `id` in the above example that makes it impossible to parse `{{ forloop.counter }}` into strings?

Comment: That isn't the same at all. Nowhere in that example do you see Django variable syntax being used *inside* another Django tag.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman : that's right, thanks for pointing it out. I'll try to learn more about the use of Django variables inside tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We can't use a Django variable using `{{ }}` inside another Django tag `{% %}`.**

Django in its docs has not used  `{{ }}` inside a template tag `{% %}` anywhere. Everywhere, it has used it separately.

**For example:**

Following 2 code snippets are valid.

```
{% firstof var1 var2 var3 %} # valid
<li> {{ some_variable }} </li> # valid
```

But, this code snippet is invalid.

```
{% firstof var1 var2 {{some_var}} %} # invalid
```

**What can be done then?**

We know that a variable which is present already in a template can be assigned inside a template tag `{%  %}`. So, if we compute a variable `my_label` beforehand then we can directly assign this variable in our template tag.

```
{% formfield field with label=my_label %} # our target
```

So, we need to compute the value `"blablabla<x>"` where `x` is the value of `forloop.counter` and store it in a variable `my_label`.

**Computing and storing the `label` value in a separate variable**

To store a value in a variable, we can use the built-in [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#with) template tag.

We might be tempted to use the below line to compute `my_label` variable, but it will lead to error as we are using the same variable syntax in a template tag again.

```
{% with my_label="blablabla{{forloop.counter}}" %} # invalid
```

So, we need to approach the problem now differently. We have to concatenate `choice` with the value of `forloop.counter` to get `blablabla1`, `blablabla2` and so on and we know there exists a template filter [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#add) which adds the argument to the value. We can use this filter.

So, we try the below code.

```
{% with my_label="blablabla"|add:forloop.counter %} # will still not work
```

But this will still not solve our problem. An empty string `''` will be assigned to `my_label` variable as we are trying to add an integer `forloop.counter` with a string `"blablabla"`.  On adding an integer with string, an error will be raised and in case of errors, Django will assign an empty string to it.

As per docs on [`add` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#add):

> This filter will first try to coerce both values to integers. If this
>   fails, it’ll attempt to add the values together anyway. This will work
>   on some data types (strings, list, etc.) and fail on others. If it
>   fails, the result will be an empty string.

So, we need to convert the value of `forloop.counter` to a string first and store it in a variable `counter_value`. This can be done using [`stringformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat) built-in template filter. Then we can use the `add` filter.

```
{% with counter_value=forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" %}  # assign counter value to a variable
{% with my_label="blablabla"|add:counter_value %} # compute value of 'my_label'
```

Now, we have the value of `my_label` with us and we can use it to get the desired result.

```
{% formfield field with label=my_label %} # use your label variable here
```

**Final code:**

```
{% for field in form %}

    {% with counter_value=forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" %} 
    {% with my_label="blablabla"|add:counter_value %} 
    {% formfield field with label=my_label %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}

{% endfor %}
```

**Note:** I was trying a slightly different version of code instead of the originally posted answer(given below) which did not lead to errors OP was getting. Thanks [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) for correcting the mistake.

The previously posted answer i.e the below code will not work as **inside a Django tag `{% %}`, we can't put `{{ }}`.**

```
# this initially posted code won't work
{% formfield field with label='blablabla {{ forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" }}' %}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still not quite sure I understand why it works with `id` in the tuto examples then. Shouldn't you have the same problem?  Why don't you have to write id="choice{{ forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" }}"?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the method given in the examples should work correctly. I tried that in Django 1.6 and it works perfectly.

Comment: Any clue why it works with `id` and not with `label`?

Comment: Besides : I get an error when I use the code you suggest : Could not parse the remainder: 's" }}?"' from '"blablabla {{ forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" }}?"' (Request Method:  GET, Exception Type:  TemplateSyntaxError, Django Version:  1.8.4)

Comment: Full disclosure : I using Django through a framework for experiments in the social sciences at http://www.otree.org/. In principle, it shouldn't make any difference, but there is always the possibility that the problem comes from the way otree handles form.

Comment: It worked for me with both `id` and `label`. Updated the ans to handle the exception. Which version of Django you are using?

Comment: Ok, thanks for following up. Django Version: 1.8.4. Problem might also come from otree. I'll ask them too. In the meantime any other suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but could not replicate your case on my machine. Did the other approach work after edit?

Comment: Not on my machine anymore at the moment, but I'll sure try once I get back to it.

Comment: This time (with the single quotes instead of the double quotes) I don't get an error, but I get {{ forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" }} again appearing "as is" in the label instead of being replaced by its corresponding value.

Comment: I am afraid i currently don't have a possible reason as to why that is happening in your case.

Comment: No worries, thanks for trying. I posted a related question on the issue queue of otree's Github repository at https://github.com/oTree-org/otree-docs/issues/13. Hopefully I can get it figured out there and come back to share the answer here.

Comment: This can't possibly ever work and I don't know why Rahul is saying it should.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for pointing that out. You are totally right, the originally posted code will never work. I am extremely sorry for that, was trying a different version of code. Have updated the ans. Should have gotten to sleep earlier yesterday!

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden Sorry mate. Was trying a different version of code. Have updated the ans. Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: @RahulGupta: No worries. Thanks for the update. In the meantime, I got another answer but one which is specific to oTree. So it solved my problems although it does not qualify as an answer to the question I posted here. Anyways, I am sure I will face the same problem again in the future. When that happens, I'll try the solution you propose and come back here to comment on it.